# Javascript grid gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-gallery

I am searching for a library for grid gallery.

Some examples exist here:

- http://piccsy.com/
- https://us.fotolia.com/search?k=las%20vegas&filters%5Bcontent_type%3Aall%5D=1&search-submit=Search

Important is that all pictures have to have similar height and fit to best order with minimum space among images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a Masonry layout library.  I've used this one in the past with good results (it's a jQuery plugin, so jQuery required).
http://yconst.com/web/freetile/